# toDataURL() returning incorrect url

Tags: meteor, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas, todataurl

I am attempting to create a pdf of a page from my meteor powered site. The page contains quite a bit of styling and some d3 charts. I have added `chipcastledotcom:jspdf` and `new3rs:html2canvas` to accomplish my goal.

My plan is to use html2canvas coupled with jsPDF's `.addImage()` function to add the charts to the pdf. As a first step towards my goal I am trying to take an existing image in the webpage (logo), drawing it onto a newly created canvas element, and then inside html2canvas, calling `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg')` which I then use as the argument for jsPDF's `.addImage()` function.

Eventually, the logo image will be replaced by images I create by converting my d3 charts to `img` elements. My issue is that the pdf is generated but the image is blank.

I don't think it's a load issue on the image since the image is clearly visible on the webpage well-before before I call the pdf generation as a user in the site.

The data url I get is below.
The `=` at the end of the data url I'm getting back from `toDataURL()` doesn't look quite right to me (although I don't really know what to expect):

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Is there a fix/work-around for this or something that I'm not understanding about `toDataURL()`?

Here is a jsfiddle (works perfectly) that demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/jdcast/tqfdkusp/.

Note, that I stumbled across this previous SO question about a similar/same issue but it didn't seem to have a resolution: [canvas.toDataURL() not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951420/canvas-todataurl-not-working-properly)

Thanks!

Comment: I dont actually understand your question.  Does the Dataurl work or not? Does it work if you remove the = ?  What has teh jsfiddle got to do with it if it works?

Comment: I don't actually know if toDataURL is working or not.  Because I don't have a lot of leads on this, I can't tell if toDataURl isn't working properly in my code or something else.  To answer your other question, it does not work when I remove the =.  The point of the fiddle was demonstrate that the same code will work in the fiddle, however for whatever reason it does not work for an already created and available image in my webpage.

Comment: Dearth this is a very difficult question to answer because I really don't know what the question is. Try to narrow it down or post your code for the image that isn't working. As it is this question doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Html2canvas sometimes does not work with the HTML which has lot of elements in the DOM (has limitation on number of elements it supports). As it parses the whole DOM elements.

In that case canvas.toDataURL() returns always the blank image.